# Segmentation fault for prime generator

Tags: c, algorithm, runtime-error

I am working on a small piece of code that generates all the primes between two numbers for a set. I decided to use a sieve (and i know theres probably a much more efficient way to do what I want than the way my code is using it) and for some reason I am getting a SIGSEGV (segmentation fault). I have looked over it quite a bit and I don't know what's wrong. I haven't been able to reproduce the error on my local machine. I get this error generally occurs when accessing out of bounds, but I don't know if thats the case here. Be Gentle, I am pretty new to C, always stuck to the higher level stuff.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char argv){
    int numberOfSets;
    scanf("%d", &numberOfSets);


    int i;
    int lowerBound, upperBound;


    for(i=0; i < numberOfSets; i++){
        scanf("%d %d", &lowerBound, &upperBound);

        //allocating memory and initializing to Zero

        int (*sieve) = malloc(sizeof(int)  * (upperBound+1));
        memset(sieve, 0, (sizeof(int)  * (upperBound+1)));

        //iterating through sieve for even numbers and marking them as non prime
        int counter = 2;
        if(sieve[counter] == 0)
            sieve[counter] = 1;
        int multiplier = 2;
        int multiple = counter * multiplier;

        while(multiple <= upperBound){
            sieve[multiple] = -1;
            multiplier++;
            multiple = multiplier * counter;

        }


        //iterating through sieve (incrementing by two) and filling in primes up to upper limit
        counter = 3;
        while( counter <= upperBound){

            if(sieve[counter] == 0)
                sieve[counter] = 1;
                multiplier = 2;
                multiple = counter * multiplier;

            while(multiple < upperBound){
                sieve[multiple] = -1;
                multiplier++;
                multiple = multiplier * counter;
            }

            counter = counter + 2;

        }

        int newCount = lowerBound;

        //check and print which numbers in the range are prime

        while (newCount <= upperBound){

            if(sieve[newCount] == 1)
                printf("%d\n", newCount);
            newCount=newCount+1;
        }


        //free the allocated memort
        free(sieve);

    }
}
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger

Comment: What are the inputs causing the seg fault? You do `counter = 2` and `siever[counter]` (on line #24) but you don't check if counter is within bounds (ie `upperBound < 1`)

Comment: `scanf("%d %d", &lowerBound, &upperBound);` check: `2==scanf("%d %d", &lowerBound, &upperBound)` and return value of malloc.

Comment: "I haven't been able to reproduce the error on my local machine" <- Aha, online judge, presumably? Then `int (*sieve) = malloc(sizeof(int)  * (upperBound+1));` is likely to receive `NULL` sometimes, since that would be more memory than you're allowed to use. Or maybe the error occurs on the next line `memset(sieve, 0, (sizeof(int)  * (upperBound+1)));` if overcommitting is turned on.

Comment: Thank you for the insight Daniel!! That was definitely it, can't believe I overlooked that... Case closed :)

Comment: Feel free to delete this question since you found your problem, it is (probably) unlikely to help future visitors (it may be generalizable to change that) and it doesn't have an answer posted. Alternatively @DanielFischer (or someone else) can post his comment as an answer and you can accept that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was not checking the result of Malloc. I was attempting to allocate an array that was to large and the allocation was failing. This left the array I was assigning to null and thus I was accessing out of its bounds.